# VBO Position Issue OpenGL, C++

Tags: opengl, vbo

I have a small problem, I made a very basic VBO cube.
It works, but when I try to move it (glTranslatef) it get's messy.

Img:
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RcEo.jpg

Code:
    http://pastebin.com/hKp0u0QQ

Why does this happen?
Also, if anyone sees a solution for the texture problem, that would be great :)

Thanks for reading :)

**Included from comments for clarification**

I'm using 3 for loops to generate a big cube (16*16*16) But their positions are messed up :/

```
for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++)
{ 
    for (int y = 0; y < 16; y++)
    { 
        for (int z = 0; z < 16; z++)
        { 
            VBOrender(x, y, z); 
        } 
    } 
 }
```

Comment: Can you post your main draw/render method? Or is `VBOrender` it?

Comment: Its the file in pastebin (The VBO) :)

(Function VBOInit, VBORender)

Comment: I'm using 3 for loops to generate a big cube (16*16*16)
But their positions are messed up :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue, I believe, is from your use of `glTranslate`.

As an example we have 3 cubes. We wish to draw them at `(0,0,0)`, `(1,0,0)`, `(2,0,0)`. According to your use of `glTranslate` the following will happen:

`Cube 1` will be drawn at `(0,0,0)` as `glTranslate(0,0,0)` is envoked.

`Cube 2` will be drawn at `(1,0,0)` as `glTranslate(1,0,0)` is envoked.

`Cube 3` will be drawn at `(3,0,0)` as `glTranslate(2,0,0)` is envoked.

Did you catch what went wrong?

`glTranslate` translates from the current matrix, not the origin. So you need to reset the matrix back to the origin `(0,0,0)` at the end of each call to `VBOrender`. So:

```
{
    glTranslate(x,y,z);

    // ...

    glTranslate(-x,-y,-z);
}
```

I suggest using some sort of matrix-stack or creating your own to avoid issues like this in the future.

Comment: Thank you very much :)
Now after 2 days I can finally continue my game :)


Added Rep!

Comment: Any idea how I can fix the Textures?

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance. I currently do not have time to investigate the texture issue, but I can look into it later tonight and edit my answer with any relevant information.